Add column count to find out multiple orders from table in Oracle DB
How do I add column count to find out multiple orders from table in Oracle DB.

I want to add last column multiple orders if order number more than once then add the counts. Expected results are shown below. In Oracle database, just add column count.

You can try using the count analytical function partitioning on the order_number as follows:
SELECT ar_trx_number, ar_trx_date, order_number, order_amount, 
      count(*) over (partition by order_number) as multiple_order
from table_name;

This code is untested.

You can create your own Fiddle to test it.
